# How to change Django database user based on login user

Tags: django

Is it possible to change Django database user based on login user. I'm using postgres db.

Comment: please describe your question proper way with explanation so we can try to understand question,what is your actual problem

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to do that? This seems likely to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I'm writting this answer according to my understanding of the question. 
For your question yes, for example if you have an application and its support  multiple users login consider 3 to 4 kind of users like..

1. Normal user
2. Superuser
3. And many more...

And if you want to switch between these users you have to made some uniqueness to find them while login. For that you should add an attribute (field)  to your database table (for example **user_role** anyway you can give your own).
Note: you should predefined all the users in this table.

And while signing up, use this user_role(u should insert 4 user_type as already mentioned above ) and make it to foreign key to your users table.

So now you saved users by giving the user_role.
While login u should send the request containing **user_role** along with user_name and password.

{
"user_role" : 2
"user_name(or email)" : "***@gmail.com",
"password" : "****"
}

If you are not find this answer as more relevant please elaborate your question so someone can help you.
Happy coding!!

Comment: For each user i created database user. When user logged in, i want use the database user created